# replacing "position:absolute" with better alternative for overlapping divs

Tags: jquery, html, css, layout

i have this big problem.

i'm making a school project site and i need to put some divs overlapping each other, at first it was enough to just put "position: absolute" in the CSS.

but then the professor said that using position:absolute will give problems when changing window size, so i had to remove it, and now all the divs are one below the other, is there a way to make them overlap without using position:absolute, one thing he told me was to use Jquery.. but how?

aniway, sorry for the lack of code but here it is:

here's the code:
this is the division of the various divs

```
<div id="demo">
        <div id="schermo"></div>
        <div id="titlescreen"></div>
        <div id="porta_destra"></div>
        <div id="porta_sinistra"></div>
        <div id="schermo_vetro"></div>
        <div id="schermo_bordi"></div>
    </div>
```

and this is the CSS formatting

```
   #demo {
    width: 800px;
    height:600px;

    padding: 8px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
 #porta_sinistra {
    position: relative;
    width: 350px;
    height: 600px;
    background: url(../img/porta.jpg) no-repeat; background-size: cover;

}
#porta_destra {
    position: relative;
    width: 350px;
    height: 600px;
    background: url(../img/porta.jpg) no-repeat; background-size: cover;

}
#titlescreen{
    position: relative;
    width: 650px;
    height: 500px;
    background: url(../img/titlescreen.jpg) no-repeat;background-size: cover; 
    margin:0 auto;
}
#schermo{
      position: relative;
    width: 800px;
    height: 600px;
    background: url(../img/schermo.png) no-repeat; background-size: cover;background-color: transparent;
    margin:0 auto;

}
#schermo_vetro{
    position: relative;
    width: 800px;
    height: 600px;
    background: url(../img/schermo_vetro.png) no-repeat; background-size: cover; background-color: transparent;
    margin:0 auto;

}
#schermo_bordi{
   position: relative;
    width: 800px;
    height: 600px;
    background: url(../img/schermo_bordi.png) no-repeat; background-size: cover;background-color: transparent;
    margin:0 auto;

}
```

but basically it gives me this result:
[div all one below the other](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Glrcy.png)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of changing the position try assigning negative margins to the div you want to overlap.

Ex. (style="margin-left:-100px;")

If you post your code it will be much easier to help.

Comment: i've tried but still no luck, it works at first with a few divs, but then becomes a big mess, aniway, now i remembered what was the code my professor told me, basically he told me to use document.ready() for every div loading, when it loads, give it a y position, aniway i don't know if it's possible... is it?

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice to have some example code to explain what you are trying to replicate, but let's see if we can figure out a reasonable solution.

My first thought would be to keep both div `positions` to `relative` and then position the second `div` atop the first `div`.

HTML:

```
<body>

        <div id="boxes">
            <div id="div1"></div>
            <div id="div2"></div>
        </div>

</body>
```

CSS:

```
<style>

    #div1 {

        height:200px;
        width:200px;
        background-color:blue;
        box-shadow:10px 10px 5px grey;
        margin:10px;
        position:relative;
    }

    #div2 {

        height:200px;
        width:200px;
        background-color:red;
        box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px grey;
        position:relative;
        bottom:150px;
        left:50px;
        margin:10px;
    }

</style>
```

So it would end up something like this [Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rxeLNv)

I can't visualize the window related issues that would arise right off the top of my head, using something like `bootstrap` would help format your `HTML` elements to all screen sizes, but that's not what your asking for so I won't go into it.

Concerning his `jQuery` comment, I don't know of any `jQuery` shortcuts that will overlap `elements` with a simple function, but you could try to use the `draggable()` function so that you can position the divs wherever they are needed.

```
$("#div1").draggable();
$("#div2").draggable();
```

Other than that there isn't much that can be said without some of your code, if you want to try some `negative margins` you could try that if the other two fall through.

[Negative Margin Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/obxLyg)

Hope this at least gives you some possibilities to think about. Best of Luck.